# com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission

Tags: android, google-oauth, gmail-api

Send mail with GMail using OAuth2.0 in Android throwing an exception  com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: Need Permission for business G-suit accounts and it is working fine with normal gmail accounts

Initialize the Google API Client as in the following.

```
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
String[] SCOPES = {
    GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,
    GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE,
    GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT,
    GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,
    GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY,
    GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM
};
```

Initialize credentials and service object.

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
  getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
  .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

// Async Task for sending Mail using GMail OAuth

```
 private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask {
        private com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;
        private View view = sendFabButton;

        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private String getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // getting Values for to Address, from Address, Subject and Body
            String user = "me";
            String to = Utils.getString(edtToAddress);
            String from = mCredential.getSelectedAccountName();
            String subject = Utils.getString(edtSubject);
            String body = Utils.getString(edtMessage);
            MimeMessage mimeMessage;
            String response = "";
            try {
                mimeMessage = createEmail(to, from, subject, body);
                response = sendMessage(mService, user, mimeMessage);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }

        // Method to send email
        private String sendMessage(Gmail service,
                                   String userId,
                                   MimeMessage email)
                throws MessagingException, IOException {
            Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
            // GMail's official method to send email with oauth2.0
            message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

            System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
            System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
            return message.getId();
        }

        // Method to create email Params
        private MimeMessage createEmail(String to,
                                        String from,
                                        String subject,
                                        String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

            email.setFrom(fAddress);
            email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, tAddress);
            email.setSubject(subject);

            // Create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Changed for adding attachment and text
            // This line is used for sending only text messages through mail
            // email.setText(bodyText);

            BodyPart textBody = new MimeBodyPart();
            textBody.setText(bodyText);
            multipart.addBodyPart(textBody);

            if (!(activity.fileName.equals(""))) {
                // Create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object
                MimeBodyPart attachmentBody = new MimeBodyPart();
                String filename = activity.fileName; // change accordingly
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                attachmentBody.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                attachmentBody.setFileName(filename);
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBody);
            }

            // Set the multipart object to the message object
            email.setContent(multipart);
            return email;
        }

        private Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
                throws MessagingException, IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            email.writeTo(bytes);
            String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
            return message;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.length() == 0) {
                showMessage(view, "No results returned.");
            } else {
                showMessage(view, output);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            Utils.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    showMessage(view, "The following error occurred:\n" + mLastError.getMessage());
                    Log.v("Error", mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                showMessage(view, "Request Cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
```

if it is business account it is moving to oncancelled() method and throwing

> com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException:
>   NeedPermission

Answer (score 0):

your auth token expired and you need to authenticate with Google again. Catch the UserRecoverableAuthException and call getIntent on the Exception object to get the authentication  Intent. Then start Activity for authentication again. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432726/userrecoverableauthexception-needpermission-in-youtube-api-v3-android)

```
try {
    // Your code
    ...
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
```